# Error code 1241, SQL state 21000: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working with a query and I get the following error code:

> Error code 1241, SQL state 21000: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

```
select * from room
where room.id in
(
select room.id, room.name, room.capacity, booking.start, booking.end
from room
left join booking on room.id = booking.room
)
```

Comment: select * from room
where room.id in
(
select room.id
from room
left join booking on room.id = booking.room
)

Comment: i guess you don't need a sub query a simple join will do that

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a subquery. You can try like this:

```
select *
from room
left join booking on room.id = booking.room
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a sub-query as the other posters have said - but the error you are receiving is because your sub-query is returning more than one column. You are telling the main query to find rows where the room.id is present in the list that the sub-query presents, but the subquery effectively returns multi columnar table of data.

If you alter it as follows then the error will go away, but you should follow the advice of the other posters and just use a join.

```
select * from room
where room.id in
(
select room.id
from room
left join booking on room.id = booking.room
)
```